# Derivation of Rindler metric

Tags: special-relativity

From what I have read the twin paradox can be resolved with the Rindler metric and without the need to bring in general relativity. Special relativity will suffice. But how does the Rindler metric get derived in the context of a constant accelerating reference frame. I haven't seen anything in my searches that answers the below questions in a clear manner.

To be more precise about what I mean, one way the time dilation is seen in non-accelerating reference frames is by considering for example light particles bouncing between two nearby mirrors in a clock and thus concluding moving clocks time slower. These thought experiments give us the Lorentz transformations a way of translating events (t, x, y, z) between two reference frames in a bijective mapping.

But what is the derivation of the Rindler metric. It presumably gives a way to map events (t, x, y, z) to (t', x', y', z') in another reference frame where one reference frame is accelerating at a constant rate. But how does one justify whatever details about it. There should be some kind of thought experiment with light bouncing between mirrors.

But moreover its not even clear to me how does the accelerating reference frame speak of time. Won't they have problems synchronizing clocks in their reference frame (which is accelerating).

Comment: You don't need the Rindler metric to explain the twin paradox using special relativity.

Comment: Is [this page on Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity/Rindler_coordinates) what you want ?

Comment: @BenCrowell John Rennie added an specific answer to his very good answers about the Twins Paradox dealing with [Appendix - why the Rindler metric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244323/104964).