# Twin Paradox Explanation via Spacetime diagrams

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

Can someone explain to me the twin paradox with the help of spacetime diagrams? (No algebra and calculus)

Comment: Here it is in pictures.  https://math.ucr.edu/home//baez/physics/Relativity/SR/TwinParadox/twin_vase.html#doppler   Calculus is unnecessary for the TP, but algebra is unavoidable.

Comment: Try my answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/507592/148184 (you can focus on the pictures and not worry about the algebra).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero that doesn't satisfy the criterion of *no algebra*